# Event bus Subscribe method called multiple times

Tags: session, vaadin, event-bus, vaadin-flow

I'am new to Vaadin and java web applications in general.

I tried to use event bus from google, this is my setup

Event bus singleton class:

```
public class Bus {
    protected static final EventBus eventBus = new EventBus(); //single instance

    public static EventBus getBus() {
        return eventBus;
    }
}
```

Place where i post my event:

```
public class MainMenuElementMain extends HorizontalLayout {

    Bus eventbus = new Bus();
    public MainMenuElementMain(String sectionTitle) {

ClickedMainMenuElement event = new ClickedMainMenuElement(sectionTitle);
            eventbus.getBus().post(event);
  }

}
```

Place where i handle the event:

```
@Subscribe
    public void menuElementClicked (ClickedMainMenuElement event) {
    add.(someComponent);
}
```

Everything is O.K. up to the time **when i post the event from other web browser**, than i got one of those two errors:

```
IllegalStateException: Can't move a node from one state tree to another
```

or

```
IllegalStateException: Cannot access state in VaadinSession or UI without locking the session.
```

I did some debugging and it seems that each time I refresh the browser or open new tab, the new instance of @Subscribe is register into the Event buss. In conclusion when i post the event all of the @Subscribe methods, from different sessions are called, which cause the error that i mentioned above.

It seems that my eventBus is a singleton sheared through all the sessions, What would be the best approach to make one instance of Event Buss for one session ?

Comment: This errors indicates, what it tells you: you are not using UI.access.  See https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-access.html#push.access

Comment: Thanks a lot, solved the mani cause of the error, but still I noticed that event bus did not behave as I wish. I mean if i have more than one session all of the Subscribe (for each session) methods are fired up. I want to make one singleton instance of the event bus for one session. I tried VaadinSessionScope but i do not use Spring so it did not work.

Comment: In that case, you will have to emulate what the VaadinSession scope is implemented to do, i.e. look for an instance in the current `VaadinSession` and if one doesn't exist, then you create an instance and store it there.